# using Zend Studio with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

Is there a comprehensive guide on how to use eclipse with zendframework?

I want to find information about the following:

- How to debug the zendframework project.
- How to use dojo/jQuery with it.
- How to create shortcuts which will make me productive.
- How to debug the project Unit testing with Zendstudio
- How to step into and step over with the project
- How to deploy project once I finished it..
- And much more..

I cant find any information. I havent found a single book on Zend Studio.

Comment: To add..I want to learn how to debug javascript/jquery with ZendStudio too..

Comment: That is **FAR** to many questions for one post.  Even if you separated each question into separate posts all the questions here are "off-topic" on this site.  Questions here need to be more specific.

Comment: Where can I learn fully about ZendStudio..cause I dont see any tutorials online

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=zend+studio+tutorial

Comment: I tried that before asking..That zend studio is useless..I think I will develop my projects on netbeans

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd When you bought Zend Studio you also paid for support. Contact your rep at Zend and I'm sure they'll be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Zend Studio 9 User Guide](http://www.zend.com/topics/documentation/studio/Zend-Studio-9-User-Guide-011612.pdf) which is found on the [Zend Studio Resources](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/resources) page.

It covers

- Creating and debugging ZF projects
- Using jQuery in your projects, javascript debugging, and prototype
- Setting up and using dojo
- Using PHPUnit Testing
- Using the debugger, including code stepping
- Deploying an application, updating it and managing deploy targets

Beyond that of course the [zf reference guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/) is a good place for information on using the actual ZF libraries like Dojo etc, the user guide just shows you how to get the features into your project, but not much on actually using them.

Comment: Thanks that was useful. Is there enough to help me build big sites?

Comment: I don't think the user guide is helpful for learning to make big sites, only to use the features of Zend Studio.  Most of learning to make big sites will come from the reference guide and the internet I think.